# Port needed to join to Domain throw Powershell

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, powershell, remote

i need to join PCs with public and domestic firewall profiles activated.
If i shutdown both firewalls profile in target Host the following command works fine.

```
Add-Computer -ComputerName $targetHost-DomainName domain.com -Credential $Global:credentialObject -LocalCredential $targetHost\localAdmin -Restart
```

But in the production scenario i need to open specific ports by using a domain policy.
The idea of this script is to remove PC from domain and add it for other reasons

So, what ports do i need to open in $targetHost firewall?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The firewall rules you need to configure in order to allow domain joining are the following:

- Server LAN to Client LAN – Only allow Ping Traffics (ICMP Type 8, Code:255)
- Client LAN to Server LAN – Only allow:

  - TCP : 88, 135, 139, 389, 445, 49152-65535 (High Ports)
  - UDP : 53, 123, 137, 138, 389, 123, 49152-65536 (High Ports)

This configuration has been reportedly tested on lab by Mr Yong Kam Wah, for full details see his blog post [Firewall Ports Required to Join AD Domain](http://powershell365.com/2016/01/19/firewall-ports-required-to-join-ad-domain/)

The full list of ports needed by Active Directory is detailed in this Microsoft document: [Active Directory and Active Directory Domain Services Port Requirements](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772723(v=ws.10).aspx)